# Spring Boot Kotlin says "Could not autowire. No beans of 'NonExistentClass' type found." on a class that clearly exists

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, websocket

I have a service with a method which I want to run as soon as the application starts, but it doesn't want to recognize the injected service. But it says `Could not autowire. No beans of 'NonExistentClass' type found.` on the `websocketService` field in the main application. I changed the import statement to `import com.example.twitchbot.websocket.WebsocketService`.

Before it was just `import WebsocketService`, but that also says `Could not autowire. No beans of 'WebsocketService' type found.`

WebsocketConfig

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.client.ReactorNettyWebSocketClient

@Configuration
class WebSocketConfig {
    @Bean
    fun reactorNettyWebSocketClient(): ReactorNettyWebSocketClient {
        return ReactorNettyWebSocketClient()
    }
}
```

WebsocketService

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.WebSocketMessage
import org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.WebSocketSession
import org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.client.ReactorNettyWebSocketClient
import java.net.URI

@Service
class WebsocketService @Autowired constructor(
    private val webSocketClient: ReactorNettyWebSocketClient
) {

    fun connectToTwitchWebSocket() {
        val twitchWebSocketUri: URI = URI.create("wss://example.com/socket") // Replace with the actual Twitch WebSocket URL
        webSocketClient.execute(
            twitchWebSocketUri
        ) { session: WebSocketSession ->
            session.receive()
                .doOnNext { message: WebSocketMessage ->
                    handleWebSocketMessage(
                        message
                    )
                }
                .then()
        }.block() // Note: block() is used here for simplicity, in a real application, you might handle this differently
    }

    private fun handleWebSocketMessage(message: WebSocketMessage) {
        // Handle the incoming WebSocket message, e.g., parse and process it
        println("Received message from Twitch: $message")
    }
}
```

main application

```
import com.example.twitchbot.websocket.WebsocketService
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean

@SpringBootApplication
class TwitchbotApplication {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var websocketService: WebsocketService

    @Bean
    fun initializeWebSocketConnection(): CommandLineRunner {
        return CommandLineRunner {
            websocketService.connectToTwitchWebSocket()
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
//  val service = TwitchbotService();
//  service.initializeBot();

    runApplication<TwitchbotApplication>(*args)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see no package declarations; I am assuming you omitted these (for brevity?).  The packages that your classes are declared in a Spring application is important, so I am going to guess what is wrong...

Let's suppose you your classes were in these packages:

```
com.example.twitchbot.config.WebSocketConfig
com.example.twitchbot.websocket.WebsocketService
com.example.twitchbot.main.TwitchbotApplication
```

The entrypoint for Spring is `TwitchbotApplication` with this annotation: `@SpringBootApplication` (with no configuration on the annotation) tells Spring to implicitly look for classes annotation with things like `@Configuration`, `@Service`, etc **from this class' package downwards**, so it search in `com.example.twitchbot.main.*`

If your structure is something like this, there are two remedies:

1. Move you entry point class up to `com.example.twitchbot.TwitchbotApplication` - then it will search in this package and below: search in `com.example.twitchbot`
2. Or leave the entry point where you have it and explicitly tell Spring where to search for classes: `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = ["com.example.twitchbot"])`

Comment: I'm new to Spring Boot and was a bit confused by `package declarations`. When I read what you wrote and checked my files, I saw that `TwitchbotApplication` had a line that said `package com.example.twitchbot`.

Then I went to `WebsocketService` and saw that that file didn't have such a declaration, so I added `package com.example.twitchbot.websocket` and added `package com.example.twitchbot.config` to `WebsocketConfig` and the error was gone.

Comment: Good then you've got a resolution.  *Packages* define a namespace that classes are declared in; real applications will have perhaps hundreds of classes so this provides a way of organising them (hierarchically) and also to get around naming conflicts where a library you use may have a `WebsocketConfig`, but you want to use the same same name... so one can qualify the class name with the package name.

Accept my answer, please!